# Web scraping search results using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Im trying to scrape german job search page with the following code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://con.arbeitsagentur.de/prod/jobboerse/jobsuche-ui/?VOLLTEXT=data%20scientist&page=1&size=10&sort=Relevanz&FCT.AKTUALITAET=100&FCT.ANGEBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS&s=2'

webpage <- read_html(url)

# In the following I try to read different elements from the html. In most of the cases I get empty result:

html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'.ba-jb-suchergebnis-oben-titel-headline a'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'.ba-jb-suchergebnis-oben-titel-headline .ng-binding'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'.jb-pristine .ng-binding'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'.ng-binding'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'h1'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'a'))
# [1] "Anleitung, wie Sie JavaScript in Ihrem Browser einschalten"
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'p'))
# [1] "Um den vollen Funktionsumfang dieser Webseite zu erfahren, benötigen Sie JavaScript. Hier finden Sie die Anleitung, wie Sie JavaScript in Ihrem Browser einschalten."
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'p:nth-child(4)'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'h2'))
# character(0)
html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'.post-box-title a'))
# character(0)
```

If you check the page all the requested elements are there. Why cannot I extract them?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please place comments in English if they are useful? Also does the site have an API? If not, is it legally scrapable(if that's even a word)?

Comment: @NelsonGon they are not really comments, but the result of the nodes 'a' and 'p'. The first says like 'Instruction how to activate JavaScript in your browser' and the secobd one says like 'In order to see all the functionalities of teh page you need JavaScript. Here you can find instruction how you can activate it in your browser'

Comment: You can't use this method for scraping data from this site because data is not available at the source code. If you click right and select "view the page source", you will see nothing! You need to use `selenium` or `phantomjs `etc. Because the data is somewhere in server side. Another option, to find XML or JSON links inside the side.

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamically updated i.e. the content you are interested in is loaded when browser facilitates javascript running. If you disable js in browser you will see:

[image]

And none of your content will have been loaded. If you inspect the webtraffic for the page you will see, amongst other things, that the page issues a POST request for an oauth token (`gettoken_cc`), passing `client_id` and `client_secret`. The returned token is then used in a later GET request with [this](https://api-con.arbeitsagentur.de/prod/jobboerse/jobsuche-service/pc/v2/jobs?FCT.AKTUALITAET=100&FCT.ANGEBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS&VOLLTEXT=data+scientist&page=0&size=10&sort=RELEVANZ,desc) querystring.  Url starts with https://api-con.arbeitsagentur.de/prod/jobboers (in case you sensibly choose not to click on that link) ......There is other info sent and web traffic. The content for the page is returned as json from that GET.  I am not going to attempt to hijack this API as I have no idea if it is public.

Ways of getting data would be potentially mimicking the steps seen in network tab or using a method like selenium for browser automation (thereby allowing js to run). Read the T&Cs first though to see if allowed. Better still, look for a documented public API.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the official api instead.
https://jobsuche.api.bund.dev/

You can use curl with parameters for fetch:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://rest.arbeitsagentur.de/jobboerse/jobsuche-service/pc/v4/jobs?was=Referatsleiter&wo=Berlin&berufsfeld=Informatik&page=1&size=50&arbeitgeber=Deutsche%2520Bahn%2520AG&veroeffentlichtseit=30&zeitarbeit=true&angebotsart=1&befristung=1&arbeitszeit=vz&behinderung=true&corona=true&umkreis=25' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Be aware that the API has no TLS cert, so that needs to be disabled for the request.
ClientID and Secret are also available on that page.
Responsed is in json format and can be parsed