# Scrape URL's beyond the first page of search results using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, extract, rvest

Please note, I am aware that there are many web-scraping questions and answers already posted, but I have not been able to solve my problem after reading them.

I have tried reading the following but haven't had success:

- [Scraping a webpage with R but 'next page' button only has event 'go to top'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228299/scraping-a-webpage-with-r-but-next-page-button-only-has-event-go-to-top)
- [Webscraping in R: How to follow a "next" button and scrape the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080770/webscraping-in-r-how-to-follow-a-next-button-and-scrape-the-page)
- [Web scraping search results using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337860/web-scraping-search-results-using-r)

and several others but I have not been successful for the site I am trying to scrape.

I would like to scrape the URLs from the following search result:

http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health

By analyzing the links that appear in the "Name" column, I am able to extract the URL's on the first page using the followng:

```
library(rvest)
webpage = read_html("http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health")

> extracted_urls = webpage %>%
   rvest::html_nodes("a") %>%
   rvest::html_attr("href")
> extracted_urls = extracted_urls[grep("?ID=", extracted_urls)]
> extracted_urls
[1] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=423" 
[2] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=98"  
.
.
.
[50] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=493"
```

The issue is there is a next button on the bottom and I am not able to access subsequent pages of results beyond the first page.

I have tried looking for patterns in the URL's of page 1, 2, 3 etc. but that was not successful for scraping.

I have tried reading other questions and answers related to scraping using R on stack overflow, but I have not been successful.

Can someone please let me know how to scrape beyond the first page of search results from this search result please?

Answer (score 0):

There is pattern fir url of pages from **page2** to **page6** (there are total of 6 pages).

```
page2 =     http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A51%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D
page3 =    http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A101%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D
page4 =    http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A151%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D
page5 =      http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A201%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D
page6 =      http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A251%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D
```

You can see for each page only change in `A51`, `A100`, `A150` etc.. which is the starting id of search result.

We can create these url by,

```
len =  seq(from = 51, to = 300, by = 50)
[1]  51 101 151 201 251

url = paste0('http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A', len, '%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D')

[1] "http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A51%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D" 
[2] "http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A101%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D"
[3] "http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A151%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D"
[4] "http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A201%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D"
[5] "http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%2C%22s%22%3A251%7D#05e2c815-e21d-4437-af2a-b351f72590d5=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D"
```

Now get links from page2 to page 6 using `for` loop,

```
#create empty vector
links = c()
#now get links
for(i in url){ 
webpage = read_html(i)
extracted_urls = webpage %>%
  rvest::html_nodes("a") %>%
  rvest::html_attr("href")
extracted_urls = extracted_urls[grep("?ID=", extracted_urls)]
links = c(extracted_urls, links)
}
head(links)
[1] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=423"
[2] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=98" 
[3] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=399"
[4] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=400"
[5] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=398"
[6] "http://www.vch.ca/Lists/Locations and Services/DispForm.aspx?ID=700"
```

Comment: I noticed this pattern too, however this doesn't work and just the first page gets scraped: 'links[1:50]' is identical to 'links[51:100]',  'links[101:150]' 'links[151:200]'
and 'links[201:250]'. Unfortunately, only the first page gets scraped.

Comment: I noticed it now. In that case, we may have to try using `RSelenium`. Instead of `ID` use `id` `extracted_urls[grep("?id=", extracted_urls)]`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click on the "next" button with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health")

web_Obj_Next <- remDr$findElement("id", "PageLinkNext")
web_Obj_Next$clickElement()
html_Content <- web_Obj_Next$getPageSource()[[1]]

remDr$screenshot(TRUE)
```

Here is another approach with RDCOMClient

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "http://www.vch.ca/locations-services?search_term=public,health"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
list_Html_Content_By_Page <- list()

for(i in 1 : 5)
{
  print(i)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  doc <- IEApp$Document()
  web_Obj_Next <- doc$getElementByID("PageLinkNext")
  web_Obj_Next$FireEvent("OnClick")
  list_Html_Content_By_Page[[i]] <- doc$documentElement()$innerText()
}
```